# Gang-of-four pattern usage in aspect-oriented-programming?

Tags: java, design-patterns, aop, gang-of-four

I am doing research on a SOA topic and i am trying to understand what gang of four say about aspect orientation. I also need to implement one of these pattern in AOP paradigm.

What would be best pattern to pick for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can splurge on a book, the [AspectJ Cookbook](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596006549) has chapters on how AOP can be used in the various GOF patterns.

Answer (score 4):

What about **Decorator**?

This seem totally natural with AOP ! The signature stays the same, but some behavior is added... :-)

Answer (score 1):

AOP concerns itself with orthogonal (cross cutting) concerns, an example of which is logging.  Given this, the pattern that would help this cause the most would be the Observer pattern.

This online book chapter:

http://www.springerlink.com/content/v7436h45532h8643/

presents the aspect-oriented implementation of five well-known design patterns: Singleton, Observer, Command, Chain of Responsibility, and Proxy.

Intuitively, I would think that Inversion of Control (IoC) would play a part as well, since it decouples the implementation of a software function from its surrounding components.